# Import existing Azure resources into local Terraform state file

Tags: azure, terraform, state, terraform-provider-azure, infrastructure-as-code

We have an extremely large number of Azure resources that were manually created a while ago, before our move to adopt Terraform. Obviously, this now means we have a huge amount of reconciliation to do, as far as synching our terraform state file with our Azure resources is concerned.

Importing the existing resources individually through the Terraform Import command isn't even an option we want to consider, as it's not only cumbersome but will be time-consuming due to the sheer number of resources at stake here.

Is there another way we could sync/import those existing resources to our local state file in bulk or in one single operation?

Comment: Google's Terraformer would make this slightly easier for resource discovery, but you would be looking at doing this iteratively, so beyond that you could wrap the commands to make it slightly better.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is very old question, but we had the same problem and used [aztfexport from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/terraform/azure-export-for-terraform/export-advanced-scenarios#export-azure-resources-to-an-existing-terraform-environment) to import our stuff, one resource group at a time.

Our process:

1. From your terraform directory locally:

   aztfexport rg -o tempdir --non-interactive --continue --hcl-only "your resource group name"
2. Go through the generated tempdir/main.tf and resource map and double check everything. Rename the auto-generated terraform object names to something that makes sense for you.
3. Once you're happy, run:

   aztfexport map --non-interactive --append './tempdir/aztfexportResourceMapping.json'
4. Move everything from the auto-generated main.aztfexport.tf file to where you want them and commit to source.

Of course, lots of stuff could go wrong, but this was the high level. This also generated a lot of objects I would have never realized were there, such as various mapping objects that terraform can manage for you that are not apparent just from the Azure portal UI.

Comment: Had a quick look on the Microsoft website and that looks like a great solution. Thank Chris. Much appreciated. Will give it a test in the coming days.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, this is one of the downfalls with Terraform at the moment. I would suggest creating a spreadsheet that has all the resource import commands,

like terraform import azurerm_xxx.xxx /subscriptions/XXXXXXXXX/resource/example and then the next line is the same and over and over. Then you can copy the entire sequential list and paste it 1 time in the terminal (where you are performing the terraform import) and just hit enter. It will take a while, but it will work.